# Photorec missing library libjpeg.so.62

Tags: libjpeg, nas, file-recovery

I am trying to undelete a file from my NAS with [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) tool on USB. However when I try to run it, i get the following error:

```
./photorec: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am aware that it's saying I have to install libjpeg package, however I can not do so because it's a WD machine running their proprietary OS.

Is there another way of running Photorec and bypass this error?
From what I can see on it's official page, the specified library is optional as stated [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Compilation#Libraries).

> Jpeg library - Optional, used by PhotoRec to improved JPEG recovery rate

Since the file is not a JPEG image I don't need this improvement.

Also I can run TestDisk just fine, however it can't find the deleted file and from what I've read, PhotoRec is better in performing such tasks.

Any help is appreciated (suggestions for another tool as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to the problem on the cgsecurity forums.

Here is a [link](https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5489&p=18345&hilit=libjpeg#p18345) to the forum post where you can download a compiled version of the libjpeg library and run Photorec.

Instructions can be found in the post itself and are very simple:

1. Download the compressed file.
2. Uncompress it in the `/ur/lib/` directory.
3. Check if library is in fact added with the following command `ldconfig -v | grep libjpeg`.
4. Run Photorec.